# Suricata to Filebeat to Kafka, routing to topics by event-type

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat, suricata

I discovered Filebeat a couple days ago.  I have it sending data to Kafka directly if I hard code the topic name in filebeat.yml.  But I can't seem to figure out how to dynamically compute the topic name based on suricata event type.  I've enabled the filebeat suricata module, and tried a number of things in the filebeat.yml topic value, like:

```
topic: 'suricata-%{[fields.suricata.eve.event_type]}'
```

But I always get this error in the log:

```
2020-01-14T23:44:49.550Z        INFO    kafka/log.go:53 kafka message: Initializing new client
2020-01-14T23:44:49.551Z        INFO    kafka/log.go:53 kafka message: Successfully initialized new client
2020-01-14T23:44:49.551Z        INFO    pipeline/output.go:105  Connection to kafka(somehost:9092) established
2020-01-14T23:44:49.551Z        ERROR   kafka/client.go:144     Dropping event: no topic could be selected
2020-01-14T23:44:49.551Z        ERROR   kafka/client.go:144     Dropping event: no topic could be selected
2020-01-14T23:44:49.551Z        ERROR   kafka/client.go:144     Dropping event: no topic could be selected
```

How do you do it?  Any sample filebeat.yml files around that route to different topics based on suricata event-type?

Comment: I think logstash has more options to inspect and route messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there is another person on earth interested in this, I got an answer that works here:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/suricata-logs-to-filebeat-to-kafka-topics-by-event-type/215179

```
topic: 'suricata-%{[suricata.eve.event_type]}'
```