# Send Pcap from Suricata to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, pcap, suricata

I configured suricata.yaml to obtain the pcap output, and I need send it to Kafka.
In suricata document, there is nothing about the configuration to send to kafka.
How can I send directly pcap output to kafka?
Could kafka listen to suricata output?
Or Do I have to use additional tool between them?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a look at how we do things at stackoverflow.com/help. You may want to edit your question (button at the bottom) so that it conforms more closely with [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Kafka doesn't "listen" to anything but its own client protocols. You will need to write your own Kafka producer process for this, I bet.

For example, [Filebeat is an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743530/suricata-to-filebeat-to-kafka-routing-to-topics-by-event-type).

Personally, I would look into NiFi for parsing and transforming PCAP data, prior to Kafka, though, as this is what [Apache Metron](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/METRON/Metron+Architecture) does